# Trimmed mean in Python

Tags: python, statistics, mean

I'm trying to calculate the **trimmed mean** of a list with a **manual function in python** but I don't know how I have to adjust my formula.

I want that you can give the function an **alpha parameter**, e.g. 0.1 (to cut 10% outliers).

My code so far (0.1 is in this case the alpha value):

```
lst[5,30,29,15,25,5,13,28,24,29] #for alpha=0.1 the list need to be adjusted --> lst[5,13,15,24,25,28,29,29]

def tmean(lst):
  s= sorted(lst)
  k= 0.1*len(lst)
  trimmed_mean= (1/(len(lst)-(2*k)))*sum(len(lst)-k)
  print(trimmed_mean)
```

The trimmed_mean with alpha= 0.1 should be 21, but I don't know how I need to adjust my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = [5,30,29,15,25,5,13,28,24,29]

def tmean(lst, alpha):
    s = sorted(lst)
    # Caclculate number of elements to trim from the beginning and end
    a = round(alpha * len(lst)
    # Check if alpha can actually remove any elements and if not return straight mean
    if a == 0:
        return sum(lst) / len(lst)
    # Remove trimmed elements from the list
    trimmed_list = s[a:-a]
    # Check if there is a list left after trimming
    if len(trimmed_list) == 0:
        return
    # Calculate average on the new list
    trimmed_ave = sum(trimmed_list)/len(trimmed_list)
    print(trimmed_ave)
    return trimmed_ave

tmean(lst, 0.1)
```

Obviously some of the above stages could be combined for more concise code, but have split into separate lines for ease of explanation

Comment: Awesome. Code works fine. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The code unfortunatley doesn't work if I have a list of for example 4 elements [1,10,20,85] and alpha=0.1 because in this case a=0 and the trimmed list would be empty because of -a. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You can add a check to see if the list is long enough to actually be trimmed by the given alpha, and if not, simply return the straight average (have edited original answer)